# saving a .v file triggers it to be opened in another window and gets E:325 in neovim

Tags: neovim, vim-windows, plugin-nerdtree, swap-file

After trying to save a `.v` file, it triggers a new window to be opened with `e:325` error with swap file already exists.

This only happens to `.v` files. This only happens when neovim is opened from that folder. This happened after trying to rename a `.v` file using Nerdtree plugin.

I tried deleting plugins, nvim-data and recopied neovim install files.

Comment: First [how do get rid of the swap files](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/14785/1841) and then [how to debug your vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841) there is 99% chances that the issue comes from a configuration in your vimrc.

Comment: Also welcome to [vi.se]!